# Saving the entity outside the transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the below code which tries to save the entity outside the transaction:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
Teacher t= new Teacher();
t.setName("jonathan");
session.save(t);
session.flush();
```

According to the definition of `save()` if used outside the transaction we need to do `flush()` to save the entity in the db.However the above code does not save it. I have to create a `transaction` and `commit` it in order to add a row in db. Why is this so?

I am using `HIbernate 4.3.6`

EDIT: I just noticed that the session.save() returns the id but only after transaction.commit() the row is added.The other question does not answer my question.Since this basically means that save() in order to add the row in db has to be in a transaction only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate save method - outside of transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413063/hibernate-save-method-outside-of-transaction)

Comment: The added question does not answer my question.My code essentially says that the save to work correctly, it has to be inside a transaction

Comment: I don't think you can get around the explicit call to the `commit` since this is the Hibernate way of transferring the data from your session to the DB. See:

http://www.tecbar.net/difference-flush-commit-hibernate/

Comment: Then what's the use of using save() outside transaction since it does not save the entity in the db.

Comment: Based on the following : https://github.com/awantik/MindTree-Hibernate-7/wiki/6.-Important-Hibernate-Functions---save,-persist,-saveOrUpdate,-update,-merge,-get,-load   -   the issue might be with the save occurring BEFORE the flush.

Comment: The git link says primary object gets saved and secondary doesn't before flush.Mine is primary so should get saved..

Comment: Did you try to first flush, then save?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work

Comment: Work with a transaction then. Any reason not to?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the purpose of using save then.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example

Sounds like there might be some bug on your end. Depends on your entity module, I suspect.....

Comment: Please look at the link I mentioned in the answer

Comment: As quoted from @ghostrider:
After a lot of searching found out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414189/1337007 which states that only flush() does not commit the changes you need to explicitly commit those changes